# Shopify Flexslider Issue: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, flexslider

I am trying to debug an issue with our flexslider jquery.

The flexslider does not load consistently, sometimes it will load, other times it will give the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
```

If the slider does load, it still does not operate properly: it freezes on the second image or which ever image you stop on when cycling through manually.

[link to our page](http://epare.com/collections/lifestyle/products/epeg01)

Answer (score 0):

this is because the script which contains the flexSlider function hasn't loaded where the

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
```

is called.

One way around this would be to ensure that the script is included before the call to flexslider is made.

So move the following above the "$('.flexslider').flexslider({" function call:

```
 <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0995/3376/t/2/assets/jquery.flexslider.js?10982885220948642179" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried to add this line resulting in but it does not fix the issue:                            <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function()            
                    <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0995/3376/t/2/assets/jquery.flexslider.js?10982885220948642179" type="text/javascript"></script>                                         {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
          animation: "slide",
          slideshow: true
        });
      });
    </script>

Comment: Sorry I place the code in a different place now and everything is loading perfectly, but there is still the issue of the Images freezing and not allowing to cycle.